# Detect HTTPS with php

Tags: php, https

I've tried to detect https using the code bellow, but the value of the global variable $_SERVER['https'] is always undefined.

```
 $secure = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off'|| $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) ? true : false ;
```

This part of code is located on the opencart's header. SSL Certificate is installed and secure connection is working properly... Any ideas?

Comment: `var_export($_SERVER);` as see what is defined, your particular setup may do things slightly differently

Comment: Are you sure HTTPS is running over default port 443? If you want to redirect traffic to HTTPS you can better use .htaccess

Comment: You shouldn't check if `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` is empty, because it can "not" exist. It would be more wise to check `isset()` first. If `$_SERVER['HTTPS_***PREFIX***']` are not set, you are not using HTTPS.

Comment: As an aside, there's no need for the `? true : false` bit -- that expression already returns a bool. Also, I *think* you've got your order of operations correct, but it's usually nice to bracket around `(A && B) || C` so that it's clear you didn't mean `A && (B || C)`.

Comment: Ok, thanks guys, but this question is actually about the undefined value of the $_SERVER['https'] not about the code...

Comment: First I've tried to do the redirect with the ataccess file, but it didn't work, it was always going into an infinite loop, the same like with the php code...

Comment: If it's in an infinite loop, your htaccess is not correct. Just open a new question about htaccess.

Comment: @bizahdee Your comment is actually a solution for my problem, so you can write an answer and I will accept it. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On this server $_SERVER['https'] is called $_SERVER['http-https']... That was the only mistake.